# How to get files from loop for zip

Tags: loop, array, ziparchive

I am working on a button which will download the images as a zip on specific posts. It works if I leave the `files` array in `functions.php` with a few hard-coded `img` links. But when I move the array to the custom post where the images I need to zip are already being looped and displayed, I can still download via button, but opening the downloaded zip I get error "Unable to expand archive. It is in an unsupported format" [image: "Unable to expand archive. It is in an unsupported format]

I have tried moving different parts of the code back and forth, like *all* of the code in the custom post, and *all* of the code in `functions.php`, to no avail. I must be not getting the `img` file `url`s properly but I'm not sure how.

This is all of the mentioned code, only in `functions.php` (except the download button), with the hard-coded image links, which works as intended:

```
$image1 = 'https://com.tripletigers/wp-content/uploads/homesweet_nowords-1920x1920.jpg';
$image2 = 'https://com.tripletigers/wp-content/uploads/V3-1920x2880.jpg';
$image3 = 'https://com.tripletigers/wp-content/uploads/SM_Single-Cover_Damn-Strait-1920x1920.jpg';

$files = array($image1, $image2, $image3);


$tmpFile = tempnam('/tmp', '');

$zip = new ZipArchive;
$zip->open($tmpFile, ZipArchive::CREATE);
foreach ($files as $file) {
    // download file
    $fileContent = file_get_contents($file);

    $zip->addFromString(basename($file), $fileContent);
}
$zip->close();

// Download Created Zip file from button via form submit
if(isset($_POST['download'])){

    header('Content-Type: application/zip');
    header('Content-disposition: attachment; filename=artist-photos.zip');
    header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($tmpFile));
    readfile($tmpFile);

    unlink($tmpFile);
}
```

This is what leads to the error, trying to get the images from the otherwise working loop in the custom post:

```
foreach( $list_posts as $list_item ) :
    if ( $list_item->post_type == 'crb_photo' ):
        if ( has_post_thumbnail( $list_item->ID ) ) {
            $img_url = get_the_post_thumbnail_url( $list_item->ID, 'crb_full_width' );              
             // this var i created for the zip, to add each image url to the array
            $getImage =  esc_url($img_url);
            // testing: prints image url. Why is that url not getting to the zip?
            echo '<h6>' . $img_url . '</h6>';
            
            // create array for zip - tried both = and .=   
            $files[] .= $getImage;
            // same result as above
            // $files[] = $getImage;
        } ?>
                            
            <li>
                <div>
                   <?php if ( ! empty( $img_url ) ) : ?>
                        <a href="<?php echo esc_url( $img_url ); ?>"></a>
                   <?php endif; ?>
                </div>
            </li>
    <?php endif; ?>
```

The `functions.php` used with above (same as first snippet but without hard-coded array)

```
$tmpFile = tempnam('/tmp', '');

$zip = new ZipArchive;
$zip->open($tmpFile, ZipArchive::CREATE);
foreach ($files as $file) {
    // download file
    $fileContent = file_get_contents($file);

    $zip->addFromString(basename($file), $fileContent);
}
$zip->close();

// Download Created Zip file
if(isset($_POST['download'])){

    header('Content-Type: application/zip');
    header('Content-disposition: attachment; filename=artist-photos.zip');
    header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($tmpFile));
    readfile($tmpFile);

    unlink($tmpFile);
}
```

When trying to open zip via command line:

[image: When trying to open zip via command line]

What am i missing in order to get those images into the zip properly?

Comment: If the URLs are fine, and you've confirmed they're fine then this looks like a generic PHP zip file generation problem not a WordPress problem. Also you're doing this in a very slow way. Instead of using `file_get_contents` to download the thumbnail URLs, why not access the file directly off the disk? Use `get_post_thumbnail_id` to get the attachment ID then use the standard attachment functions to grab the path/filename of the file for the image size you want

Comment: also have you tried using `addFile( $file, basename( $file ) )` instead of reading it in as a string and using `addFromString`?

Comment: Thanks for the comments. I have been trying these ideas and still am stuck. Working on a better code snippet soon to show what I've been trying.

Comment: note that the files you're trying to zip up themselves could be a part of the problem. It could even be that because you've downloaded the zip 50 times, it's assuming this is part 50 of a larger collection, etc

Comment: I have been changing the name of the downloaded file along the way, `filename=artist-photos.zip')` to `filename=artist-photos-2.zip')`, and so on. Hopefully that would have prevented what you mentioned. I'm just getting back to this but will update my question code later with where I'm at with it..

Comment: how are you confirming that `$files` is not empty and contains valid values? There's no information about the process other than what the final result is at the moment, so we don't know if it's a WordPress issue or a general PHP issue. If we can figure out that it's WP specific then we'll have useful information to arrive at a fast answer. If not then it's a generic `ZipArchive` question that should go on stackoverflow where more PHP devs will see it who aren't necessarily involved in WordPress

Comment: Hi again Tom - the person who asked me to do this task in the first place decided to stuff JavaScript right inside the PHP, and do it that way. Which is unfortunate. So I haven't come back to this. But if I had, I was not checking for not empty and definitely would and should have done that!

Comment: on further reflection it may be that your loop that fills in the `$files` array is also printing HTML and as a result that HTML is ending up in the downloaded file. There's a lot missing from this question, e.g. there is never a code snippet that shows the entire code that was tried, and it's not clear if it's inside a function or in the root of `functions.php`, or on a hook. Also `file_get_contents` shouldn't be needed if the files are on the same server, but even then a lot of hosts disable using that function to do HTTP requests/downloads for security reasons

Answer (score 0):

As the files are within the same WP installation (not a remote), you don't need to download the file using get_file_contents(), try to add the file using its absolute path of the attachment.

```
if(isset($_POST['download'])){
    $tmpFile = tempnam('/tmp', '');
    $zip = new ZipArchive();
    $zip->open($tmpFile, ZipArchive::CREATE);

    
    foreach( $list_posts as $list_item ) :
      if ( $list_item->post_type == 'crb_photo' ):
        if ( has_post_thumbnail( $list_item->ID ) ) {
          $zip->addFile(get_attached_file(get_post_thumbnail_id($list_item->ID )));
        }
      }
    }

    $zip->close();

    header('Content-Type: application/zip');
    header('Content-disposition: attachment; filename=artist-photos.zip');
    header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($tmpFile));
    readfile($tmpFile);

    unlink($tmpFile);
}
```

**Note** typed the code in this editor, may contain syntax error.

Comment: I have been trying this and still cannot get it to work (fixed the syntax errors). When i use hard-coded image array, i could not even get that to work with `addFile` - only with `addFromString`. Using `$zip->addFile(get_attached_file(get_post_thumbnail_id( $list_item->ID )));` as you wrote gives same error. Can you share a way to use `addFromString` and `file_get_contents` maybe?